# I need to disable Disqus comments pre-approval, but i can't find where

Tags: comments, disqus

I've tried contacting Disqus support but they haven't answered.
I need to disable pre-approval for comments but i can't find where to set that option. Could anyone help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution: you gotta disable Disqus 2012 features on your website (pre-moderation haven't been implemented on Disqus 2012 yet, despite being almost 2013 already).

Here's the article where i found the solution: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/708758-how-to-enable-settings-missing-from-disqus-2012

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as the right answer!

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu There's a delay of 2 days until he can do that.

Comment: @Pothi Kalimuthu Done :)